# Read specific line of a file and then set it as a variable

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed

How do I print a specific line of a file new.sh (line 60 in this case) and then set what is printed as a variable?

I want to make sure the new info will be printed in the correct section of the file before executing.

`cat -n new.sh | sed -n '60p'`

??????
??????

```bash
if [ "$DATA" ]; then
    if [[ "$DATA" == "<data>" ]]; then
        sed -i '60i < new data will be added here. >' new.sh;
    elif [ $DATA != '<data>' ]; then
        echo "Error"
    else
        return 0
    fi
fi
```

Comment: not clear enough! please clarify it

Comment: Trying to build a command within a script that does the follow:

Comment: Trying to build a command within a script that does the follow: 1. Displays line 60 of .sh file. 2. Make what is displayed (line 60) a variable. 3. Check that line 60 is "<data>", if it is add new data to new.sh file. In this case "<new data will be added here. >". If line 60 isn't "<data>" then display "Error".

Comment: I want to make sure the line is being added to the correct part of the file before running the command. In this instance it needs to be added to the line directly below Line 60 which is <data>

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
data=$(sed -n 60p new.sh)
```

but if the goal is just to insert the line before line 60 only if line 60 is the string `<data>`, it seems easier to just put that logic in `sed`:

```
sed '60 { /^<data>$/i\
<new data>
}' new.sh
```

Doing this doesn't give you the error message that you had before, so perhaps you want something like:

```
if ! awk '60 == NR && /^<data>$/{ print "<new data>"; ok = 1} 1 END{exit !ok}' new.sh; then
    echo Error >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LINE=`sed -n 60p <new.sh'
echo "$LINE"
if [ "$LINE" = "<data>" ]
then
    sed -n 1,59p <new.sh
    echo "some new data"
    sed -n 61,$p <new.sh
fi > output.sh
```